# RethinkDB filter and retrieve value from nested array

Tags: rethinkdb

Using the following query:

```
r.db('somedb').table('sometable')('users')
```

I get the following data from the result:

```
[
   [
      {
         "fn": "dpw",
         "u": "usertwo"
      },
      {
         "fn": "dwd",
         "u": "userone"
      }
   ]
]
```

I would like to **take the field "u"** and **specify lets say "usertwo"** and **get the value of "fn"** for that "u". I want to have the result **filtered using ReQL** so that I am not just parsing the json result in nodejs as the result will be enormous eventually. What would be the best and **most efficient** approach. I am new to RethinkDB and would appreciate if you could **explain** the answer as best you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you exactly want, but from my understanding, this is what you are looking for:

```
r.db('somedb').table('sometable')('users').filter(function(user) {
    return user("u").eq("usertwo")
})("fn")
```

You seem to have an array of array of users. if that was not a typo, the query should probably be

```
r.db('somedb').table('sometable')('users').nth(0).filter(function(user) {
    return user("u").eq("usertwo")
})("fn")
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using your second solution, nth(0) was the part I was missing!